# How to write regex to stop replace &nbsp; character between span or div tags?

Tags: asp.net, regex, c#-4.0, htmlwriter

I want to change my below regular expression in such a way that It should not replace/remove `&nbsp;` if there is `&nbsp;` found in aspx page. then skip to replace with blank character

Below expression work fine but only issue is that it removing all the `&nbsp;` character.

In my aspx code I wrote `<span class='clscode'>&nbsp;</span>` in this type of tag inner text I wrote `&nbsp;` character.

Here is my C# code.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 /// my code 
 }

    private static readonly Regex t = new Regex(@">\s+<", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static readonly Regex lb = new Regex(@"\n\s+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter()))
        {
            base.Render(htmlwriter);
            string html = htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
            html = t.Replace(html, "> <");
            html = lb.Replace(html, string.Empty);
            writer.Write(html.Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

I need below type output.
for example:
my page having so many 
This is a test example

```
<div id="dvtest"> <space> <space> <space>
<span>&nbsp;</span><space> <space>
<div id='test2'> sample &nbsp;&nbsp;text&nbsp;    </div></div>
```

//... like this 
tags.
I need output like this.

```
<div id="dvtest"><span>&nbsp;</span><div id='test2'>sample &nbsp;&nbsp;text&nbsp;</div></div>
```

**Note:  Here `<space>` means white space invisible character**

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you post a before/after sample?

Comment: giving space in explanation will not make us understand your question. please write proper question i can create any expression

Comment: @merhardik I modified my question. pls check. do you required more information what exactly I want.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I added what I need before and after sample. do you  need more details?

Comment: sure i will give its solution

Comment: for &nbsp you want to use space ?

Comment: @merhardik yes, I want to take as it is if &nbsp; , It should be remove <space> character only from page.. I using mention reg expression code to my C# code.

Comment: @Abhishek Can you try my below answer

Comment: @VigneshKumar I am trying.

Comment: @Abhishek - Your code is working! What's the problem? `<div id=\"dvtest\">   \r\n\t\t<span>&nbsp;</span>  \r\n\t\t<div id='test2'> sample &nbsp;&nbsp;text&nbsp;    </div></div>` ends up as `<div id=\"dvtest\"> <span>&nbsp;</span> <div id='test2'> sample &nbsp;&nbsp;text&nbsp;    </div></div>`.

Comment: It removed &nbsp; from inner tag also. I does'nt want to remove this &nbsp; character. do you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

If you can't use an HTML parser oriented solution to filter out the tags, here's a simple regex for it.

```
string noHTML = Regex.Replace(inputHTML, @"\n$", "").Trim();
```

<kbd>[Regex Demo](http://rubular.com/r/R8rc53G2YZ)</kbd>

Comment: I don't want to replace &nbsp; character from all pages. it should remain intact. only remove <space> character. only remove white space from aspx page.

Comment: I write <space> it means only white space. it not mean to <space> I could not show that white space character. so instead of space character I wrote <space> form..

Comment: @Abhishek am sorry about it. I have changed solution now

Comment: @Abhishek I have added regex to match whtie space

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter()))
    {
        string re1 = "( )";
        base.Render(htmlwriter);
        string html = htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
        Regex r = new Regex(re1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Match m = r.Match(html);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            String c1 = m.Groups[1].ToString();

            html = html.Replace(c1.ToString(), "");

            writer.Write(html);

            // Console.Write("(" + c1.ToString() + ")" + "\n");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: My main goal is to remove all white space character from aspx page. except &nbsp; character.

Comment: I modified my question. you can  understand easily. In my aspx page I wrote aspx content & tags. so from whole page I want render html code with minified version so I removing the white space not want to remove &nbsp; character.

Comment: yes. this will react as same. it will remove only white space from your input text